# Basis of a Subspace of a Space of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

How does one find the basis of the following subspace of $2\times2$ matrices, and what is its dimension?

$$ V:=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 
x-y & 2x+y+3z \\
-18x-9y-27z & -7x+7y 
\end{pmatrix}:x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$$
Note that every matrix in the basis has to have rank of 1.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Is "Note that every matrix in the basis has to have rank of 1." part of your working?

Comment: I need to find a basis for V in which every matrix in the basis has one row of zeros

Comment: Well, I managed to get both of them with rank 1. Having a row of zeros might be a problem.

Comment: just a question, whats the role of k here?

Comment: Did you intend to write on my answer?  The role of $k$ is to be some constant which we will calculate later.

Answer (score 1):

$\left\{
\left(\begin{matrix}1&2\\-18&-7\end{matrix}\right),
\left(\begin{matrix}-1&1\\-9&7\end{matrix}\right),
\left(\begin{matrix}0&3\\-27&0\end{matrix}\right)
\right\}$

spans the subspace of the space of matrices.

Let's treat the matrices as vectors, specifically, we can multiply each matrix by a non-zero constant and we can subtract any multiple of a matrix from another matrix.

Subtracting $\frac{1}{3}$ the third matrix from the second matrix and $\frac{2}{3}$ the third matrix from the first matrix gives:

$\left\{
\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&-7\end{matrix}\right),
\left(\begin{matrix}-1&0\\0&7\end{matrix}\right),
\left(\begin{matrix}0&3\\-27&0\end{matrix}\right)
\right\}$

Since the first 2 matrices can be obtained from each other by multiplying by a non-zero constant ($-1$), we can delete one of them.

$\left\{
\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&-7\end{matrix}\right),
\left(\begin{matrix}0&3\\-27&0\end{matrix}\right)
\right\}$

This is now a basis for the space, as the matrices are clearly linearly independent. The dimension of the space is $2$.

Let's try to make the matrices of rank $1$.

$\left\{
\left(\begin{matrix}-k&3\\-27&7k\end{matrix}\right),
\left(\begin{matrix}k&3\\-27&-7k\end{matrix}\right)
\right\}$

We claim this spans the previous vector space if $k\neq0$. In fact, the sum of the 2 matrices is $2\left(\begin{matrix}0&3\\-27&0\end{matrix}\right)$, and the first minus the second is $-2k\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&-7\end{matrix}\right)$.

The determinant of the second matrix is 0, so $-7k^2-3(-27)=0$, and $k=\sqrt{\frac{81}{7}}$.

$\left\{
\left(\begin{matrix}-\sqrt{\frac{81}{7}}&3\\-27&7\sqrt{\frac{81}{7}}\end{matrix}\right),
\left(\begin{matrix}\sqrt{\frac{81}{7}}&3\\-27&-7\sqrt{\frac{81}{7}}\end{matrix}\right)
\right\}$

We can check that the determinant of the first matrix is also $0$.

Answer (score 0):

This can be written as $\begin{bmatrix}x- y & 2x+ 3y+ z \\ -9(2x+ 3y+ z) & -7(x- y)\end{bmatrix}$ or, letting a= x- y, b=2x+ 3y+ z, $\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ -9b & -7a\end{bmatrix}= a\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -7\end{bmatrix}+ b\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -9 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.    Now, do you see what a basis is and why this space has dimension 2?

Comment: both matrices dont have a rank of 1 so its not correct